# Is there a way to hide the “What's New” tab on Chromium-based browsers in the Developer Tools pane?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, brave

I'd like to prevent the “What's New” tab from ever opening when I <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> into the Developer Tools pane for Brave, Chrome, etc.

It's annoying whenever I am trying to inspect elements because the “What's New” tab occupies the same sub-pane space as console, causing an entire new pane to appear below the inspection pane.

I think if I were able to permanently hide the What's New tab, it would prevent the entire sub-pane from appearing. Anyway to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Go to Settings under Dev Tools:

> “Settings > Preference > Appearance”

Uncheck "Show What's New after each update"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pndkv.png]

Comment: Sadly, Chrome doesn't seem to respect this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Question is currently:

> "Is there a way to hide the What's New tab on Chromium-based browsers in the Developer Tools pane?"

Yes there is! Click the `X` on that tab:
[image]

Or, if you see this as a pane inside the dev tools pane, like so:
[image]
You can click the `X` on the entire pane (top right corner of that pane) or press <kbd>esc</kbd> while dev tools has focus (i.e. just after opening it)

I presume you never want to be shown it again (as is my desire), in which case [user9703047's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1586205/167207) should work, but Chrome doesn't seem to respect unchecking that setting, and will continue to force you to see the what's new pane for the foreseeable future.

Comment: This completely ignores the "I'd like to prevent the What's New tab from ever opening"

Comment: @Anigel Please read my whole answer, the last paragraph addresses exactly that

Comment: shit "answer"..